# Leaving behind feature does not work with my Airpods

Tags: iphone, geolocation, airpods, find-my

I was able to configure the "leaving behind" feature between my Apple Watch 7 with my iPhone 11. Works great, however, I want to do the same for my Airpods Pro. The configuration option is not there and I don't know what to do. All devices are on the latest stable version (iOS 15.1, Airpods 4A400, Watch 6.1), I tried to do it again with Airpods paired, with Airpods playing music, with Airpods connected to my Watch. Nothing works.

What else can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[appleinsider](https://appleinsider.com/articles/21/10/13/how-to-use-left-behind-alerts-community-finding-pairing-lock-with-airpods-pro-airpods-max):

> There have been sporadic reports recently of the new features not showing up for some users and others seeing the left-behind alerts as "not supported" on AirPods Pro.
>
> Apple will likely issue a bug fix eventually, but in the interim, the best solution appears to be a **reset and re-pair** procedure on impacted AirPods. Failing that, try **signing out and then back in to your iCloud account**.

Comment: Just for the record, I haven't tested re-pairing yet. But I assume it is a fair reply and marked this as the solution. Not sure why ppl downvoted, thanks!